# jquery attr() not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attributes

I am using jQuery and would like to retrieve the 'id' attribute
of a clicked element, which in this case is a  element.

Kindly check the image below. Notice that the returned string whenever
I use the attr() method in jQuery is somekind of an object (or array perhaps).

The expected value is printed below the next line. It returns the right value when
I use this:

```
$(this)[0].id
```

When an element is clicked, Isn't it the element is the one being reference in 'this'?

Why does attr() return an array?

[image]

Comment: Work for me on Chrome (last version): http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/23/, It should depends on the webkit debug console that you are using.

Comment: Printing the object data is normally done when you use command ´console.log($(this));´

Comment: I didn't get your last comment. Yes I know how it is printed in the console. Strange that it works on js fiddle. Will retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I isolated the code and figured out that the tinymce plugin for jquery is making a conflict. Check out the static.html

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbk8hxqjw34hzn1/jquery-attr-not-working.7z

Sorry for the archive, Dropbox won't let me upload 9mb and above so I have to compress.